# Error using custom app-pool identity for database login

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis-7.5

I am new to IIS and MS SQL Server (coming from a Apache MySQL Environment) so hopefully I will include enough details for you guys to help me!

I am converting my web app from using hard coded database credentials (currently SA :/ ) in the Connection String in web.config.

I removed the username and password and put in "Integrated Security=SSPI".  The website is  configured with a dedicated app pool and that app pool Identity is set to the domain account I want it to use.  When I attempt to use the web app I get an error.  When I look into the SQL Server logs I see "Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.  Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not an IIS expert myself, however it's clear that your website/web app is trying to connect anonymously to SQL Server via `NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON`.  You could add that login to SQL Server, but [it's probably a very bad idea](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34569/sql-server-2008-is-nt-authority-anonymous-logon-login-mandatory).  I'd go back to SQL authentication in your web.config.  Just don't use `sa` (or any other login with sysadmin permissions).

Comment: @user3858056, you are wise to avoid using the sa account for routine data access.  Also, Windows authentication is more secure and should be used whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Add (or modify) the element below to the system.web section of your web.config.

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/134ec8tc(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: We already have that and the system.web section and it is still coming up as using anonymous.

Comment: Is the database and web server are in the same domain, and the account is in that domain too?

Comment: I had to set it to False.  Otherwise it was still passing Anonymous.  Once I set it to false it passed the credentials set for the identity in the App Pool.